# Describing a matrix group (with integer coefficients) through conditions on the coefficients.

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, modular-forms

I'm wondering if there's always a (not too complicated?) way to characterize a matrix group by conditions on the coefficients.

I know if I'm dealing with matrix groups over a field, then it's sort of a question of seeing if the matrix group is Zariski-closed, which would correspond to polynomial conditions on the coefficients, though I'm not necessarily only interested in polynomial conditions, and I want to work with integer coefficients.

More specifically, I've got four matrices $A,B,C,D$ in $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, and I'm looking at the subgroup of the group generated by these four matrices (which have the sole relation $DCBA = 1$), such that the number of times $A$ or $C$ appears in any word is even.

Actually, (Formatting looks weird, these are meant to be $2\times2$ matrices and the coefficients are ordered as top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right)
$$A = \left[\begin{array}{ll} 1 & 5 \\
0 & 1\end{array}\right]$$
$$B = \left[\begin{array}{ll} 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1\end{array}\right]$$
$$C = \left[\begin{array}{ll} 11 & 20 \\
-5 & -9\end{array}\right]$$
$$D = \left[\begin{array}{ll} 11 & 25 \\
-4 & -9\end{array}\right]$$

($A,B,C,D$ actually generate the congruence group $\Gamma^1(5)$)

In fact, if we let
$$M = \left[\begin{array}{ll} -2 & -5 \\
1 & 2\end{array}\right]$$
then $C = MAM^{-1}$, and $D = MBM^{-1}$.

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing the formatting (see the sidebar item "Basic solution")

Comment: I took the liberty of changing $B$ to a matrix with determinant $1$ rather than $0.$ 

Comment: Note that your matrices do not seem to fit the group, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group_Gamma0#Modular_group_.CE.931.28r.29   

Comment: @Will: $\Gamma^1(5)$, not $\Gamma_1(5)$; $\Gamma^1$ has the top right entry divisible by 5. I corrected $B$ again, so it is now in $\Gamma^1(5)$ and the claimed relation $D = MBM^{-1}$ holds. But it's not totally clear to me what the question here is, and as far as I can see it has nothing whatsoever to do with modular forms.

Answer (score 3):

The question is rather vague, but I hope that the following is helpful.

You seem to want a solution to the membership problem for your subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.  Note that such a solution is known not to exist in $SL(4,\mathbb{Z})$, which contains a copy of $F_2\times F_2$; I suspect its existence is open for $SL(3,\mathbb{Z})$.

However, $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is group-theoretically much nicer, being as it is virtually free.  The membership problem is certainly solvable here quite efficiently, though I don't know an implementation off the top of my head.  The methods involved go back to Stallings's notion of  folding.  A google search turned up the paper '[Membership problem for the modular group](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=TI&pg5=AUCN&pg6=PC&pg7=RT&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=membership&s5=schupp&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq)' by Gurevich and Schupp.

Comment: By the way, if you are correct and the subgroup generated by $A,B,C,D$ is free on $A,B,C$ (I haven't checked), then 'the subgroup ... such that the number of times A or C appears in any word is even' is generated by $A^2, C^2, AC, B, ABA^{-1}$. 

Comment: Note also that the fact that the membership problem is not solvable in general shows that there are subgroups which are not cut out by a family of polynomials.